# In which hazard does cache miss fall into?

Tags: assembly, cpu-architecture, mips32, cpu-cache

There are three types of hazard in the five stage of pipeline:-

1) Control hazard : - if/jump

2) Data hazard :- RAW(read after write), WAR ( write after read), WAW (write after write)

3) structural hazard :- Structural hazards are when two instructions might attempt to use the same resources at the same time ( as in [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classic_RISC_pipeline))

which type of hazard does cache miss fall into?

Comment: Good overview [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hazard_(computer_architecture)). A cache miss isn't a hazard as such, though cache eviction / coherence might be considered a similar issue.

Comment: thank you for the response Brett.But cache miss will create a stall right? Lets say in ld and st case.

Comment: the cache is part of the memory system and outside the pipeline, from the pipelines perspective it is simply a memory access with a normal (long) access time, where a cache hit is simply a memory access that is faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of a hazard as a misprediction - the pipe speculatively advances each cycle, assuming there are no conflicts. It might be wrong in the cases you describe - if the next stage comes from the wrong program-counter/inst-pointer, or if the calculation source wasn't updated in time, or some resource wasn't ready in time.
Now, a cache miss is not normally considered in this taxonomy, perhaps because it's implementation specific. you can say the same about varying-latency execution. You don't have the data ready so you just stall, there's no actual risk here of using stale data or fetching bogus code from the wrong path. 
Note that a memory access could still be RAW (load after store, in that case), and count as a data hazard just like a register-bound RAW.